# How can i use special charackters like " * and ? " in the " in (...) " part of a FOR loop

Tags: variables, for-loop, batch-file, special-characters, wildcard

i want to do the following

```
set _1=*.*
set _2=*.lng
set _3=*.exe
...
```

in a for loop like that:

```
set COUNT=0
for %%f in (*.*, *.lng, *.s, *.exe, *.sfx, *.64.sfx, rar*.lst) do (
 set /A COUNT+=1
 set _!COUNT!=%%f
)
```

But that doesn't work. I tried to escape with " ^ " and also tried

```
For /F "useback" %%f in ('*.*, *.lng, *.??s, *.exe, *.sfx, *.64.sfx, rar*.lst')
```

but with this i only get " _1=*.* " and the other "_2" to "_7" is missing.

Can anyone explain how to assign those wildcard-Strings to variables within a loop ?

Comment: `useback` is an invalid parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set COUNT=7
set "var=*.* *.lng *.s *.exe *.sfx *.64.sfx rar*.lst"
for /l %%a in (1,1,%COUNT%) do for /f %%b in ('for /f "tokens=%%a" %%i in ^("%var%"^) do @echo(%%i') do set "_%%a=%%b"
set "_"
```

It works here.

Comment: I suppose the OP wants to create the variables from a list. Not using the variables to echo them.

Comment: I need seven for loop variables (boring), a char for %LF% (your code) or a "dynamic token". I built one with the for /l loop and needed an additional for /f loop to separate the for /l variable from "tokens". [sorry for my English :(]

Comment: A little bit complex but an excellent solution. Solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a FOR/F loop, as the normal loop tries to match wildcards.

To loop through a list of values in one string you can use linefeeds in the string.
First the text to parse is delimited by commas, then I replace all commas with linefeeds.
So FOR/F can loop through the list and produces per line one token.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "text=*.*,*.lng,*.exe"
set LF=^


rem *** Two empty lines are required here for creating the LF
for %%L in ("!LF!") do set "text=!text:,=%%~L!"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ("!text!") do (
 set /a count+=1
 set "_!count!=%%a"
) 
set _
```

Comment: Also a good solution i can maybe use later on for similar programming tasks.